Having problems with Gate Driver outputs
I am currently using the ADUM4221 gate driver to drive a half-bridge. It receives a pair of inverted and non-inverted signals , to drive the High side and Low side MOSFETS, from a dSpace RTI1104 control box. The problem which I am currently facing is that the driver only gives one output depending on the duty cycle: from 0.1 to 0.55 only the low side output gives out the PWM signals, and from 0.55 upwards only the high side output sends out the PWM signals. The other output has no signals. The PWM signals are observable on both the inputs on the input side at all duty cycles. This phenomenon has been observed upto a frequency of 100kHz (which is my desired operating frequency). It has not been tested for frequencies above.
The input side of the driver is power with Vcc of 5V. The output side of the driver is powered by two independent 15V power supplies placed on different grounds.
NOTE: It should be noted that due to an issue with the MOSFET footprints, capacitors of 10nF (the Ciss value for the MOSFET which is planned on being used) are being used instead at the gate and source of the MOSFETs, for testing.

Please add data sheet hyperlinks to the main components and make an improved resolution schematic that is readable all over without overlapping text.
